# list available PCIe slots in my laptop

Tags: terminal, hardware, pci

I want to add a second Graphic card to my laptop but I want to know if there is any PCIe slot available without having to open it.

Does it have any command I can run to get this info?

`lspci` lists a bunch of entries that doesn't seem to be physical slots.

PS:

I'm running Pop!_OS 22.04

The first graphic card is integrated to [the processor](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/196655/intel-core-i711370h-processor-12m-cache-up-to-4-80-ghz-with-ipu/specifications.html).

Comment: dmidecode **might** be a better way to go to discover what hardware slots are available, but typically the bios is not configured to give the correct information. The chances that you can add another internal gpu is close to zero. You probably want to be shopping for external gpu, which tend to connect via thunderbolt or usb-c.

Answer (score 0):

Any laptop should come with a manual that tells you whether and where you can install additional hardware; anyways, I'm not aware of any secondary internal graphics cards that you could install into a laptop, so I honestly think you might be asking about installing a product that does not exist.

Anyways, no. `lspci` only knows about the PCI hierarchy, but can't know whether some unused port on a switch or a root complex is connected to a connector.

Answer (score 0):

The only command which *might* tell you about available slots of any kind is `dmidecode`, but it relies on information from the firmware, and it’s common for this information to be incomplete.

Some laptops can take pluggable MXM GPUs, and this should be indicated in the laptop’s manual. It is however relatively uncommon, and even more uncommon for a laptop *without* a discrete GPU to support adding an MXM GPU. Even when it is possible, finding an appropriate GPU is difficult — many models are proprietary, and MXM GPUs can’t be bought new by end-users so the only option is to find an appropriate pull from another laptop.